# how do make my solution which is in the () equal to the actual surface area?

Tags: javascript

this is what i did so far and the answer in the () does not equal to the actual surface area?

```
<script>
  function getrandomnumber(min,max,notthese)
{
num=min+Math.floor((max-min+1)*Math.random());
return(num);
}


function surfaceareaofabox(num)  
{
  var a=getrandomnumber(10,100,"");
   var b=getrandomnumber(10,100,"");
 var c=getrandomnumber(10,100,"");

var surfacearea=(a*b+a*c+b*c)*2

        var str=i+") Find the surface area of a box with sides "+c+", "+a+" and    "+b+". <br>("+surfacearea+")"+"<br>"

  return (str);
```

}

```
  document.write("Solve the following word problems: (Note: The number in       ()     is the answer to the question."+"<br>"+"<br>")

 for (var i=1;i<=3;i++)
  {
   document.write(surfaceareaofabox()+"<br>");
  }
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Questions here must state the objective, what you've tried so far and where you got stuck.  I'd suggest you read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Why is there a `2` at the end of this line:  `var volume = (a * b + a * c + b * c) 2`?

Comment: In Javascript, you need a `*` to indicate multiplication: `var volume = (a * b + a * c + b * c) * 2`.

Comment: also, my solution in the brackets are wrong do u know why?

Comment: I give up here.  We fixed your code formatting for you to make it nice and readable and then you edited it and messed it all up again.  Code here should be nice and readable with appropriate and consistent indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you have not clearly stated what it is you are trying to accomplish, it seems that you are trying to write some code that will calculate the surface area of a 3D rectangular shape, i.e. a "box" with dimensions a, b and c.

You are on the right track but there are several problems with your code.

First, you provide the correct formula for the total surface area, but you incorrectly label it as `volume`. In fact, the volume would simply be `a * b * c`. Assuming that you do, in fact, want total surface area, you should change the variable name to, for example, `surfaceArea`. *(You have corrected this problem already in one of your edits of your question.)*

Second, you are using random numbers for the three different dimensions each time. This is fine, but the person running the program (you or someone else) will have no idea what those initial dimensions are, because the program does not repeat them back to the person running the program. Therefore, you need to not only show what the surface area is, but also what the original dimensions are. *(Again, you seem to have corrected this problem in one of your edits to the problem.)*

Third, your `getrandomnumber` function includes a parameter that is never used, `notthese`. You should therefore eliminate that parameter, as well as the double quotation marks that you used to satisfy that parameter requirement. (If, for some reason, you *do* need to include that third parameter for a reason that is not clear in the way you asked the question, then you need to use that parameter somewhere within the body of that function.)

Fourth, your function `surfaceareaofabox` uses a parameter that is also never used, `num`. However, this function also never defines where the variable `i` came from. I suspect that you intended `num` and `i` to be the same thing. However, in that case, you need to use the same variable name in both places. Note, however, that for reasons I discuss below, you probably shouldn't even be including and/or using this parameter where you have placed it.

Fifth, the purpose of the function `surfaceareaofabox` is overly complicated. You are currently using that function to (1) obtain three random dimensions, (2) calculate the total surface area of a box with those dimensions, and (3) output the results. That's not illegal, but it's also not good practice, particularly when the name of your function implies that it's purpose should only be #2 from the above list. I would suggest doing activities #1 and #3 from the above list within the `for` loop that you describe, and only call `surfaceareaofabox` to do exactly that, calculate the surface area of the box. (Note that this is only one of many possible strategies, but I think it's a decent approach.) After calculating the three dimensions, you then need to pass those dimensions in to the `surfaceareaofabox` as parameters, and you also need to *not* pass in the calculation number, i.e. the `num`/`i` that you have included.

Sixth, it is unclear why you are doing the whole thing three times. If that is what is required of you, then fine. However, there is nothing inherent in the mathematical problem you are trying to solve that suggests that you need to do this. I mention this in particular in case you are mixing up the fact that you need to calculate three random dimension values with the fact that you are calculating the surface area three times (which, in the end, would require calculating nine random dimension values). If, for example, you were supposed to use a `for` loop to calculate the three random dimensions, then your approach is incorrect. However, that is impossible to tell from the way you asked your question, so my answer assumes that you actually *do* want to do the surface area calculation three times.

Seventh, using `document.write` is legal, but really not a good way to approach adding content to a web page. Again, it's not illegal, but it is very rarely used in properly constructed web pages. However, if you are just starting out, or you have only just learned this way of adding content to the web page, then fine.

Eighth, you need to make variable names, including function names, readable. For multi-word names, this is typically done in one of two ways: either (1) use underscores, like `get_random_number`, or (2) use what is called camel case, like `getRandomNumber`. Either is more readable than `getrandomnumber`, even though this is, technically, still legal.

Ninth, you have forgotten to use `var` in front of your first use of `num` in your random number generating function.

Taking all of this into account, I suggest the following code:

```html
<script>
  function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
    var num = min + Math.floor((max - min + 1) * Math.random());
    return (num);
  }

  function surfaceAreaOfABox(a, b, c) {
    return (a * b + a * c + b * c) * 2;
  }

  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    var a = getRandomNumber(10, 100);
    var b = getRandomNumber(10, 100);
    var c = getRandomNumber(10, 100);
    var surfaceArea = surfaceAreaOfABox(a, b, c);
    var str = "Calculation #" + i + ":<br/>";
    var str = str + "Box dimensions: a=" + a + "; b=" + b + "; c=" + c + "<br/>";
    var str = str + "Total surface area of the box: " + surfaceArea + "<br/><br/>";
    document.write(str);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew I will take all of your constructive criticism  into accountant and fix my skills on coding and your code that you helped me on is exactly what i was looking for thanks again.

Comment: Because you are relatively new to StackOverflow, I would just like to tell/remind you that (1) I help you by answering your question, and (2) you help me by accepting my answer by clicking on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from hollow to green. Please do so if you think my response "answers" your question. Also, please do not re-post the code from my answer as another "answer"...that's just not how Stack Overflow works. All the best with your coding.